Voice typing in Windows and online Word dictation in Romanian triggers *** instead of the word "cum"=how
I am (or was) very impressed with the voice dictation in windows 11 (to the point that as a Linux user I am often coming back to windows in order to write by dictating). It works very well with the languages I've used - English, French and also Romanian, excepting for this unexpected error where the very common Romanian word meaning HOW (cum, pronounced /ˈkum/) is typed *** (3 asterisks).
I think this has something to do with the "profanity/sensitive words filter" which cannot be disabled in windows 11 voice typing, as said under How do I get dictation To stop auto Censoring Curse words:

The Windows +H shortcut opens dictation by default on Windows , the
setting is already written into the system code and cannot be changed.

This is especially stupid because there is no profane or otherwise vulgar word in Romanian that sounds like that.
The situation gets even dumber when I realized that in online MSOffice Word dictation there is a setting to disable sensitive words filtering, but that unchecking it is not saved! (But let's say that is another matter for another time.)
What can one do in this situation?

But cum is also a Latin word, which is often used in phrases like magna cum laude. Does it guess in what sense is the word being used via context?

I don’t believe you can do anything other then use a third-party application that doesn’t attempt to identity and filter profane words.

@ApoorvPotnis - Of course, but the word meaning "how" is even more frequent. This is a bug. Beside the feature of not allowing setting off the "profanity filter". This is at the beginning, Romanian voice typing didn't even worked in Windows 10.

@Ramhound - Easier said than done on the desktop. On Android yes, of course. I was giving Microsoft a serious try after many years and it quickly becomes a nightmare. A comic one too: in Romanian they also block the word "anus" (the Latin scientific term that is), but not the really vulgar equivalent! - Interestingly how such mishaps clearly emphasize the downside of closed code and rigid control. Not allowing the disabling of that "morality filter" is nothing less than madness.

@cipricus - I could give you a few ideas if software recommendations were allowed.
